# Oracle JDK-1.8 installation issue on Ubuntu-16.04-LTS(xenial i386)

Tags: 16.04, apt, java, docker, oracle

With below Dockerfile trying to install Oracle JDK-1.8 on `xenial i386 image`. But it fails during docker build.

```
# Install oracle jdk 1.8
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get -y update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer && \
    java -version
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

If fails with below error.

```
E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer && java -version' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Have tried with `add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa` this shows below error.

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)
The command '/bin/sh -c add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa &&     apt-get -y update' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How shall i install `Oracle JDK-1.8 on Ubuntu-16.04LTS (xenial i386)`?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Dockerfile added `ENV LANG C.UTF-8` and able to install Java.